# tcolorbox image not fitting

Tags: graphics, formatting, tcolorbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={8in, 11.9in}, margin=0.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=Definition,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,lower separated=false]
    text

\includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight,width=\linewidth,valign=t]{ok.png}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

This is what the image looks like: [image]

How do I move the image to the right and change the image size? It is too large.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do two things:

- Add `\tcblower` to move to the second side of the box
- Don't specify the height of your image. `\includegraphics` will scale it proportionally for you.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!75!black, title=Definition, sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top, lower separated=false]

  text

  \tcblower

  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{example-image}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, you have enough reputation to share ;)

Comment: Yes. Given that the whole SE system will implode at any moment, it makes a lot of sense to go for reputation. (Even without the looming implosion it does not make much sense.) ;-) ;-)